# How can I mock camera input for espresso tests?

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

I use camera for barcode detection in my app and I would like to write espresso test. Problem is I don't know how to mock camera in espresso, only thing that is covered in tutorials is system camera app started with intent, but I have my own camera source etc.

Anyone have experience with that?

Answer (score 1):

To mock custom camera intents with espresso you can use this kind of intending :

```
Intents.intending(IntentMatchers.hasComponent(YouCustomCameraView::class.java.name))
            .respondWith(ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, yourCustomIntent))
```

And add this dependence to your gradle to use intents mock with espresso

```
 androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2')
```

So when you'll perform a click that should launch YourCustomCameraView it will directly give you the this ActivityResult instead with yourCustomIntent. The camera view sould not launch.

Comment: Yeah, that I know, I wanted to provide own video stream for testing image recognition in camera.

Comment: I only tried camera photo data but it should be the same for stream video. I suppose you have to watch what your camera video activity return and create your own dummy one and put it in your intent (something like intent.putExtra("data", "yourDummyVideoStream) or intent.data = yourDummyVideoStream)